# How to pass Form2 button click value to Form 1

Tags: c#

I have two forms Form1 and Form2.
on Form1 button click , I want to open form2 in which yes and no buttons are there in the form2.
When user click on button yes, form1 textbox should display the value in form1's textbox.
What i have done is as follows:
On Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Alert AlertObj = new Alert();
        string a=AlertObj.Text.Length.ToString();
        string val=Alert.buttonVal();
        AlertObj.Show();

        if (val == "Yes")
            textBox1.Text = val;
        else
            textBox1.Text = "No";

    }
}
```

on Form 2

```
 public partial class Alert : Form
{
    public Alert()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static string result = string.Empty;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result = "Yes";
        Form1 obj = new Form1();

        this.Close();
    }
    public static string buttonVal()
    {

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `MessageBox` with `Yes` and `No` buttons??

Comment: actually i am learner and i want to work with multiple forms...what if i have multiple buttons in form2 and i want other then yes or no

Comment: then see @Alireza's answer. It'll help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simpler ways to do this. But as you asked:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Alert AlertObj = new Alert();

        if (AlertObj.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
            textBox1.Text = AlertObj.ResultText ;
        else
            textBox1.Text = "No";

    }
}


 public partial class Alert : Form
{
    public Alert()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ResultText {get; set;}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResultTest = "Yes";
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting value `DialogResult` will close the form automatically. No need to close it

Comment: @Fabio Thank you buddy. Sometimes I confuse this with something else which I don't remember :D

Comment: Hey Alireza, what is val?

Comment: Thanks !! Please like my question if u can.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, by using `overloaded constructor`, passing it `Reference` of `Form1 TextBox`

**Form 1 Code:**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Alert AlertObj = new Alert(Ref textBox1);
        AlertObj.ShowDailog();
    }
```

**Form2 Code:**

```
    public partial class Alert : Form
    {
        TextBox txt;
        public Alert()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Alert(Ref TextBox txt1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txt=txt1;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt.Text ="Yes";
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems overkill to pass reference to Control, for updating only `Text` property. Purpose of `Alert` is returning value. Not updating another form controls